Number of distinct lengths when cutting a rope into the ratio $p:q$
There is a question about it in AoPS, but no one answered there, the link: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1859981p12577385
Given two positive integers $p$ and $q$,
a rope of length $1$ is progressively cut into smaller rope pieces as follows: In each step, all the currently longest rope pieces are simultaneously divided into two parts in the ratio $p : q$.
After an unknown number of steps, the longest rope pieces have length $x$.
Determine, as a function of $x$, the number $a(x)$ of different rope lengths present at that point in time.
What I tried:
If $p=q$, then in each step we cut the rope into equal parts, so in each step all ropes have the same length, thus $a(x)=1$
Then suppose WLOG that $p>q$. Then I experimented with $p=3$, $q=2$ and with the 'extreme' other case $p=99$, $q=1$ and noticed that the amount of distinct lengths grows if the longest rope pieces has the highest power in the fraction (so of the form $\frac{x}{(p+q)^n}$ and the others have in the exponent at most $n$. At least I hope so.)

The amount of distinct lengths should grow by at least 1 each time. It grows by 2 if it is of the form $ p^n / (p+q)^n$.

If you reframe this as $1=p+q, p>q$ you can arrange lengths like a binomial triangle (e.g., 1st row $(p+q)$, 2nd row $(p+q)^2$) but with coefficients all of 1, so you just have entries like $p^2, pq, q^2$ for row 2. The cuts go in order of the biggest to least terms, which will advance downward with a leading edge on $p^n$ side. Because $p^k < q <p^{k-1}$ for some $k$, at the $k+1$th stage you will first split on $q$ to make $q^2$, and from then on your cuts should advance diagonally in staggered ladder-like waves shaped, the steepness/vertical jumps depending on $k$.

Since you can figure out the $p,q$ coefficients from the length at which the procedure stopped, the next few that would be cut must define the wavefront so you can see where the zig-zag border should be and how many uncut segments must exist at that moment.

@RobinSparrow I believe that just $ p^k  < q < p^{k-1}$ isn't sufficient. You'd need the full $\log q / \log  p $. EG You need to figure out when making the $q^3$, how to deal with the $q^2 $ and $q$ level. $\quad$ I wasn't able to get a nice description for $a(x)$, so I might be missing something (or the question didn't turn out the way they intended).
